# how to mark as checked for associated values in Rails 4 checkbox with many to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, checkbox

i am creating a user ACL i have 2 models one is `users_group` and another is `access_sections`.
Now let's supouse I have 2 access_sections (pages, users)
I wanted to associate both `access_sections` with `users_group`,
Now here what i have already did 
I created many to many association, added new join table `access_sections_user_groups` 
Whenever i add new user group I pass instance variable to get all available access_sections the I show them as a checkbox in a new user group form, once i check any of access section I loop through in array and insert all elements in 'table `access_sections_user_groups`' with `users_group` id and `access_sections` id everything is working now i wanted to do that when I edit usergroup my checkbox should be checked if the specific `access_sections` is associated with user_group

user_group_controller.rb

```
 def create
 @user_group = UserGroup.new(group_params)


if @user_group.save
  flash[:notice] = "User group added !"
  flash[:type] = "success"

  if params[:user_group][:access_sections].present?
    params[:user_group][:access_sections].each do |f|
      UserGroup.find(@user_group.id).access_sections << AccessSection.find(f)
    end
  end
  redirect_to(:action => "index")
else
  flash[:notice] = "error while adding new group!"
  flash[:type] = "danger"
  render("add_new")
end
end
```

user_group/_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.label("Add section to Access Control ") %>

<% @acl_sections.each do |k| %>
  <%= f.check_box(:access_sections, { :multiple => true }, k.id, nil) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work

```
f.check_box(:access_section_ids, { :multiple => true }, k.id, nil)
```

Hence you need to update your model like this way:

```
def create
  if @user_group.create(user_group_params)
    # ...
  end
end

def user_group_params
  params.require(:user_group).permit(access_section_ids: [])
end
```